# How can I pass email to the req.body received as {params}

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

In a page, I am grabbing login user `email` from localStorage() and passing with req as `{params}`. How can I add the email to the `req.body` ?  I can see email displaying at `userEmail` in server side and body has data.

Now it is throwing not notNull: email cannot be null violation exception.

[image]

`Aboutus.js`

```
const [newDetails, setNewsDetails] = useState({ _id: '', newstitle: '', newsdetails: ''})
const loginUserEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');

 const onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setNewsDetails({ ...newDetails, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

    const onSubmit = () => {
        const newsData = async () => {
          try {
            const params = {
              email: loginUserEmail,
            };
            const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/news', newDetails, {params}); 
            console.log("News post message:" + res.data.success);
            if (res.data.success) {
              setIsSent(true);
            }
            else {
              console.log(res.data.message);
              setHelperText(res.data.message);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
          }
        }
        newsData();
      }
```

`server.js`

```
app.post('/service/news', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.query.email;
    const newDetails = await NewsModel.create(req.body);
    console.log("Server side news post method log:" + newDetails);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (e){
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const newDetails = await NewsModel.create({...req.body, email: userEmail})`

The function was looking for a property called email. When you previously passed userEmail, it was passed in as userEmail. Doing email: userEmail will pass it as email.

Comment: Yes I haven't pass that, I need to pass userEmail to `NewsModel.create`, may I know how to do that ?

Comment: You could try doing 
`const newDetails = await NewsModel.create({...req.body, userEmail})`

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that earlier, still its giving same error news.email cannot be null. I think if we pass separately the email will not be available in req.body ?

Comment: `const newDetails = await NewsModel.create({...req.body, email: userEmail})` ?

Comment: Cool that is working, how does the email will get inserted into req.body by this method ?  `{...req.body, email: userEmail}`